# GeoJSON in MapBox GL JS: Can I set layout and paint properties individually for each feature?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

For example I have some GeoJSON here that represents airspace regions and they have in their properties "HIGHALT" in feet, so it would be very natural for me to map this to the `fill-extrusion-height` paint property (which takes meters), however these values are on an individual feature basis rather than across the entire set of features.

I tried just adding it into the `properties`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [identity function](https://www.mapbox.com/help/gl-dds-ref/#property-functions) to specify the field with your heights.

Two useful examples:

- [Extrude polygons for 3D indoor mapping](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-extrusion-floorplan/)
- [Display buildings in 3D](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/)

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for... doc was hard to find. Thanks for linking me to them!